# How can I implement pull-to-refresh with MooTools?

Tags: mootools, pull-to-refresh

I want a pull-to-refresh function that can be used on desktop browsers with the mouse and via touch on mobile touch devices.

There seem to be several solutions using jQuery, however I could not find anything appropriate for MooTools.

How would you do it using MooTools Core/More, or do you know of a small script that does it ?

Comment: What have you tried? If there are several jQuery solutions what about just porting one over to Mootools?

Comment: Sure I could port one but why should I if there were one for MooTools ? Why reinvent the wheel ? I have reimplemented and rewritten countless things already just because there was nothing suitable for MooTools but this is extra work and maintenance. Thus the question. It is hard to believe that I am the only one using MooTools to need this thing.

Comment: @Archimedix: checked around, inclusive with the developer behind moobile and the suggestion is the dependency-free iScroll (https://github.com/cubiq/iscroll). Its mantained and works good. If you want to make a moo-version maybe others will be interested. Might be worth to ask in our [google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/mootools-users)